# n-gram language model smoothing

Tags: computational-linguistics, python

I use the corpora of webtext to train n-gram model in NLTK.And i use katz back-off smoothing to solve 0 count-problem.But one problem is:while the smoothing used in based-on characters language model,r* (computed good-turning) >r(original count),as a result the counting coefficient alapa<0.what's the problem?
And that problem doesn't come up in based in word language model.
i need your help ,thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question focuses on programming details. It is better asked on stackoverflow.com or in [datascience.se].

Comment: I disagree. I think this is definitely an NLP question.

Comment: Is really r* > r? I thought that because some weight is backed off the r* counts are actually smaller than the real counts?

Comment: yes,i has turned the method of Witten-Bell backoff.